# TYPO3 password protection without username

Tags: passwords, typo3, password-protection

I want to have a subpage on my website that is password protected. There should be a list of 6-digit passwords that allow access to the site. However, I don't want the user to type in a username. He should only type in one of the 6-digit passwords.

Any ideas, how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default login for TYPO3 uses username and password. If you only needed 1 password you could create 1 user and use a custom template with the username in a hidden field. However, since you want multiple passwords, there is no default way to do it without creating your own authentication service.

It's a bit much to explain how to create an authentication service here, but you can read the documentation here https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Authentication/Index.html.

You can also look at an example like https://github.com/tschikarski/shibboleth, which is a but complicated, but you'll mainly need to look at `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addService` in `ext_localconf.php` and the `getUser` and `authUser` functions in `Classes/ShibbolethAuthentificationService.php`.

Answer (score 1):

With Typo3 mechanism, a password is always associated with a user name, I think you should do it by yourself :

- if the content is from one of your extension, you can easily do it
- if it's not the case, I think you could use a hook before page is displayed and manage password access in that hook
- or you can make a specific template with which you can conditionally manage rendering

Answer (score 1):

Why don't reverse the usage?

Create FE-users with the selected passwords as username, then assign all users the same password.

For the login you change the login form:

- The password field gets a default value (the password you had set to
  all accounts) and is hidden
- The input field for the username is changed into a browser passowrdfield so the input is hidden by asteriks.

Then you might change the errormessages as they would confuse the user about his username so he only enters a "password".

Answer (score 0):

There now exists an extension for that, too:
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/sessionpassword

With that, you just have to create a specific usergroup for your purpose,
set a password an d include the plugin on the desired page.

Works for me in that case.